# How to use git-svn for svn update？

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

**Problem Background:** I use git-svn for project management because my company uses SVN for its projects, but I want to use git locally because he has easy branch management and many good tools. **Problem:** Some of the code managed by SVN is set with access rights, before, I didn't have access to some of the code, but with the development of the features later, my supervisor opened up the access to the code so that I can access the code, in SVN I can use `svn update` to update the code down, but for git-svn I use `git svn rebase` doesn't bring the code down, does anyone know how to fix it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

1. rebase "...fetches revisions from the SVN parent of the current HEAD", i.e. (AFAICU) can't add new, enabled for you, trees
2. If "opened up the access to the code" in the same objects, to which you had access before (some subtrees in known branches, f.e.), you can try to get code with `fetch`
3. If you got access to extended tree (new branches?), you may have to change `[svn-remote]` section in the repository $GIT_DIR/config file and add (missing, but needed&) keys for branches|tags by hand and [`fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#Documentation/git-svn.txt-emfetchem) only after it

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I don't quite understand what you mean, can you point out what command I should use and what are the steps to execute the command? To clarify, my SVN opened code permissions for the same branch.